# Create XML dataset with the same table name as initial data set in DBUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, fixtures, dbunit, database-testing

I'm trying to create an initial DB state in DB Unit like this...

```
public function getDataSet() {
        $primary = new \PHPUnit\DbUnit\DataSet\CompositeDataSet();
        $fixturePaths = [
            "test/Seeds/Upc/DB/UpcSelect.xml",
            "test/Seeds/Generic/DB/ProductUpcSelect.xml"
        ];
        foreach($fixturePaths as $fixturePath) {
            $dataSet = $this->createXmlDataSet($fixturePath);
            $primary->addDataSet($dataSet);
        }
        return $primary;
    }
```

Then after my query I'm attempting to call this user-defined function...

```
protected function compareDatabase(String $seedPath, String $table) {
    $expected = $this->createFlatXmlDataSet($seedPath)->getTable($table);
    $result = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable($table, "SELECT * FROM $table");
    $this->assertTablesEqual($expected, $result);
  }
```

The idea here is that I have an initial DB state, run my query, then compare the actual table state with the XML data set representing what I expect the table to look like. This process is described in [PHPUnit's documentation for DBUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) but I keep having an exception thrown...

`PHPUnit\DbUnit\InvalidArgumentException: There is already a table named upc with different table definition`

Test example...

```
public function testDeleteByUpc() {
    $mapper = new UpcMapper($this->getPdo());
    $mapper->deleteByUpc("someUpcCode1");
    $this->compareDatabase("test/Seeds/Upc/DB/UpcAfterDelete.xml", 'upc');
  }
```

I seem to be following the docs...how is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually unrelated to creating a second XML Dataset. This exception was thrown because the two fixtures I loaded in my `getDataSet()` method both had table definitions for `upc`.